# Why is adding multiple gradients not working?

Tags: html, css

I want a simple radial gradient, with a darker linear tone coming from below...

```
 div {

   width: 1000px;
   height: 500px;
   background: radial-gradient(yellow, orange), linear-gradient(180deg, red, rgba(0,0,0,0));
 }
```

But only the radial gradient is showing up, not the second. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The radial gradient is being placed over the linear gradient. Since both colors' opacity are 100%, the gradient above blocks the gradient underneath.

Just switch the order of the gradients.

```css
 div {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 500px;
   background: linear-gradient(180deg, red, rgba(0,0,0,0)), radial-gradient(yellow, orange);
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```